# GestureRecognizer on retina screen

Tags: ios, gesture, retina-display

The pixel number of each side of retina Device is double of non-retina device.
When using UIPanGestureRecognizer,i can get velocity of the pan in pixels/second in the coordinate system of the specified view by calling - (CGPoint)velocityInView:(UIView *)view,but do I need divide the return value by 2 to get a correct velocity?I have read the document from apple,developer do not take care the x2 problem.But the comment in UIPanGestureRecognizer.h make me confuse.

Comment: Reading the one line of the documentation would answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it returns it in `points` per second, that is not pixels per second.

Apple chose for `points` as a unit because it is not dependent on the `pixel densitiy` of the screen. Meaning that the 3G and the iPhone 4 have the exact same result with this gesture recognizer. The iPhone5 has a bigger screen but that doesn't change anything you have to do with what the recognizer returns.

Thus to your answer: No, you should not divide it by 2, apple is taking care in their API's.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!
In UIPanGestureRecognizer.h, I found that:
- (CGPoint)velocityInView:(UIView *)view;                           // velocity of the pan in pixels/second in the coordinate system of the specified view.

This comment from apple make me confuse.
Thank you again.

Comment: @HenryLaw Thats an odd comment.. but in the documentation its talking about points per second, which in this case makes a lot more sense anyways